# What does this ($ln=~/.*[A-Z]1.*\t/) || ($ln=~/.*[A-Z]\]1.*\t/) || ($ln=~/.*[A-Z]\@\]1.*\t/) mean in a perl script?

Tags: perl

Being a newbie in perl, I've tried searching what each character in the code signifies but for this particular line in the code. It was the condition in an If statement. Kindly help me out with this. Thanks :)

```
if(
    ( $ln =~ /.*[A-Z]1.*\t/     ) || 
    ( $ln =~ /.*[A-Z]\]1.*\t/   ) || 
    ( $ln =~ /.*[A-Z]\@\]1.*\t/ )   )
```

Comment: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ is your friend.

Comment: use regex101.com, it is a very good breaking-down-of-regex to get you through complex regex

Comment: this single regex is equivalent: `/[A-Z](?:\@?\])?1.*\t/`

Comment: Yes, gskinner.com/RegExr is so good! Thanks @slayedbylucifer

Comment: @nrathaus: your http://reg101.com link is EXCELLENT! Very clear [but it is for "recent" versions of regexp engines only, I fear... still, very good to describe a regexp]. A nice one is also: **http://www.regular-expressions.info/** (which often precises when this or that works on this or that regexp engine! Ex: how backslashes \ are interpreted within `[...]`, which depends on the implementation!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a condition looking to match one of three different regular expressions.

The first one is looking for a string that matches any character zero or more times .*, followed by a capital letter [A-Z], followed by the number 1, followed by any character zero or more times followed by a tab \t.

The second ones does pretty much the same, just also looking for a `]` character between the capital letter and the 1, while the third is looking for an at (`@`) symbol as well.

Comment: Thanks Robbert! I found your explanation simpler :)

Comment: note that in each regex the initial `.*` is useless; all the same strings would match (or not) with it removed from the regex (assuming the special match variables $& or $` are not used later in the code)

Answer (score 4):

The segment:

```
if ((something) || (something-else))
```

simply checks if either of the condtions is true, so what you have there is a check to see if `$ln` matches any of those three regular expressions (`=~` meaning a regex match in Perl). In other words, it's looking for a string containing:

```
.xy1.t
```

(that's not a regex string by the way, I've assigned my own meaning to `.` for example) where:

- `.` matches any sequence of non-newline characters.
- `x` is an uppercase letter `A` thru `Z`.
- `y` is either nothing, `]` or `@]` (this is the only difference between the three regexes).
- `1` is the literal `1`.
- `t` is the tab character.

Comment: Thanks @paxdiablo :) Your answer too helped me.

Comment: No probs, @piscean_1993, Rob needs the rep more than I do :-)

Answer (score 4):

The correct answers have been given, but I wanted to add something.

First off, I think it is important to note that this code is written by someone who is not very skilled at regexes, which makes it a lot harder to understand. It is quite possible to simplify this code considerably.

```
if(
    ( $ln =~ /.*[A-Z]1.*\t/     ) || 
    ( $ln =~ /.*[A-Z]\]1.*\t/   ) || 
    ( $ln =~ /.*[A-Z]\@\]1.*\t/ )   )
```

This code performs three regex matches, using almost the exact same regex three times. When they are lined up, it is easy to see that the only difference is `\]` and `\@\]`. This difference is small enough that we can merge the regexes together into one:

```
$ln =~ /.*[A-Z](\@\]|\])?1.*\t/
```

The `(\@\]|\])?` part meaning that we can match either `\@\]`, `\]` or nothing.

Also because this is simply a check, and not a capture or an iterating match, we certainly do not need it to begin with a string of optional wildcards `.*`. This is very basic regex knowledge, that a regex is not anchored by default. The end of the regex has a similar thing, but in this case requires our match to end with tab `\t`. So we are left with

```
if ( $ln =~ /[A-Z](\@\]|\])?1.*\t/ )
```

With the same meaning as explained by others. It checks if the string in the variable `$ln` contains:

- One upper case letter, followed by
- An optional string of a literal `]` or a literal `@]`, followed by
- A literal `1`, followed by
- Any number of non-newline characters, ending with a tab `\t`.

Because we suspect that the person who wrote this is not skilled, we might suspect that some of the nuances in this regex are wrong. For example, did the person really mean that we should match only `]` or `@]`, or is `@` also valid? Is it really important to match a tab somewhere further ahead in the string `.*\t`, or did s/he add that just because s/he thinks that the regex must cover all of the string, like s/he thought when adding `.*` at the beginning? It is possible that we can simplify the regex all the way down to:

```
/[A-Z]\@?\]?1/
```